# New Firebase: Changing Database URL dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

In the old Firebase, I used to be able to get reference to different database dynamically at run time (say, switching between dev and prod db, or even switching to a user-defined database URL) because the database URL is passed in as a string when instantiating a db reference.

In the new Firebase, the database URL (along with other settings) live inside `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

Is it still possible to do what I did in the old way? Or is there another recommended way to achieve that?

Comment: I've not switched to the new firebase, having troubles with dynamic URLs. How do you manage to add event listeners, such as child_added on dynamic URLs for different users? Stuck :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found the answer anyway. Instead of the usual setup, you'll have to initialize the app manually like so:

```
let firOptions = FIROptions(googleAppID: googleAppID, bundleID: bundleID, GCMSenderID: GCMSenderID, APIKey: nil, clientID: nil, trackingID: nil, androidClientID: nil, databaseURL: databaseURL, storageBucket: nil, deepLinkURLScheme: nil)        
FIRApp.configureWithOptions(firOptions)

let firebaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

You can name them too with `configureWithName:options:`

Further documentation on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/interface_f_i_r_app

Comment: Do you know where I can find more info on this? The link you have provided returns  404 error. Thanks.