# Download and use files stored in Firebase Storage from different projects

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Storage to store images in FB, I'm saving download URL in Realtime DB and to retrieve some photos from the storage, I'm using this code:

```
   let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
    imageRefInDB.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        // Get download URL from snapshot
        let downloadURL = snapshot.value as! String
        // Create a storage reference from the URL
         let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL(downloadURL)
        storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            } else {
                let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
    })
```

My problem is I wanna use some of my photo that are inside another Firebase project. For example, the download URLs will be: 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/PROJECT1.appspot.com/o/someMedia&token

When in my current project, the bucket is different like :
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/PROJECT2.appspot.com/o/someMedia&Token

When I try to using the `PROJECT1` files in my current `PROJECT2`, I'm getting the following error:

```
reason: 'Provided bucket: PROJECT1.appspot.com does not match bucket specified in FIRApp configuration: PROJECT2.appspot.com
```

Is there a way to enable downloading theses files from other projects like a setting in Firebase without retrieving them with regular URL downloads?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried that once and it lead to an unhappy time. In my case I had two different buckets for my images, so I had to find an alternate solution.

If you have only a single bucket, you can try configuring that bucket in your `FIRApp`:

```
let firOptions = FIROptions(googleAppID: googleAppID, bundleID: bundleID, GCMSenderID: GCMSenderID, APIKey: nil, clientID: nil, trackingID: nil, androidClientID: nil, databaseURL: databaseURL, storageBucket: storageBucket, deepLinkURLScheme: nil)        
FIRApp.configureWithName("anotherClient", options: options)
let app = FIRApp(named: "anotherClient")

let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage(app: app!).reference()
```

*Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492377/new-firebase-changing-database-url-dynamically), so you may need to modify it to suit your needs*

With that app, you can then use the Firebase Storage API as you're already doing to download the image data.

If you have multiple buckets (as I had), you either have to configure multiple apps or (as I did) handle downloading the image from the downloadURL yourself (without using the Firebase Storage API):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: downloadURL) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
    });
}
```

Comment: Frank is correct. In the future we plan on allowing linking other buckets from the same project in (so you can have an images bucket and a backups bucket, for instance), but for now, you'll have to use the other `FIRApp`.